# Can I curve an L-shaped shower curtain rod myself?

Tags: bathroom, shower

My hall bath has a partially enclosed tub.  I have researched an L-shaped shower curtain rod and know that they exist, however, I would like the longer part of the "L" to be curved to allow for more room in the tub when taking a shower.  Can I curve the longer portion myself successfully and easily without harming the curtain rod?

Comment: Welcome to DIY.StackExchange! "Shop for me" type questions are off topic here, I've removed that portion of the question for you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps.

It depends on how brittle/ductile the rod is.  Its likely steel, which has a wide range of properties.  There may be finish cracking issues.  The wider the radius, the more likely the success.

I would experiment on a similar but simpler rod.  The methods I suggested [**here**](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/27859/what-advantages-does-bending-copper-pipes-have-over-joining-many-parts-without-b/27876#27876) would be the least expensive tooling.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: Clarification, in case it's needed: The wider the radius OF THE CURVE (not of the rod), the more likely the success -- in other words, a gentler curve is going to be a lot easier. And since most shower curtain "rods" are hollow, you also have to worry about the tube collapsing on the inside of the curve. Compare the cost of possibly failing with the cost of tracking down one that already exists -- or constructing it from an already-curved rod, a short straight rod, and a coupler of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, if you had some basic workshop tools you could, you could very easily curve the shower curtain yourself, but the problem is making the curve look professional.

- Upon bending the tubing (note i say tubing, since I am relatively
  certain it will be tube)  you will most probably create kinks all
  over at the pressure point of the bend.
- Your rod is also most likely chrome covered, which is likely to crack and flake off when bent

If you are keen to experiment, I would fill the tube with fine sand, then close the ends with a stopper. Then you will need to look for somewhere to bend the rod, typically one would use a set of rollers with the desired bend profile, however in the DIY sense the best thing you will find is to look for a strong tree (specifically a split or v in the branches)  whereby you can gain leverage for the bend.  Then very gentle pressure all down the bend seam will begin to bend the bar.

The better thing to do here would be to take the curtain rod to a metal shop and have them try, in which case I would go for stainless steel or aluminium which will not flake.

Answer (score 1):

Depending the diameter of the rod. It's possible you could use a pipe bending tool, like the one intended to bend conduit for running electric wires.

Comment: This is a great suggestion. Be careful to avoid kinking the rod. Most shower rods are relatively thin walled and/or not a good ductile material.